# TikZ redefined \xrightarrow causes unequal line skip around the equation

Tags: tikz-pgf, line-spacing, tikz-cd, baseline, xrightarrow

I recently encountered some code redefining `\xrightarrow` etc. with `tikz-cd` to avoid possible issue with `unicode-math`. The code looks like this:

```
\RequirePackage{tikz-cd}
\newbox\xratbelow
\newbox\xratabove
\renewcommand{\xrightarrow}[2][]{%
\setbox\xratbelow=\hbox{\ensuremath{\scriptstyle #1}}%
\setbox\xratabove=\hbox{\ensuremath{\scriptstyle #2}}%
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\xratlen}{max(\wd\xratbelow, \wd\xratabove) + .6em}%
\mathrel{\tikz [->, baseline=-.75ex]
\draw (0,0) -- node[below=-2pt] {\box\xratbelow}
node[above] {\box\xratabove}
(\xratlen,0) ;}}
```

The source where I saw this code says that it comes from Antal Spector-Zabusky, though I didn't find the code on this site. There's one problem with this code though: the use of `baseline=-.75ex` makes the line skip before and after the equation unequal. Is there any way to fix this?

Below is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{parskip}

\RequirePackage{tikz-cd}
\newbox\xratbelow
\newbox\xratabove
\renewcommand{\xrightarrow}[2][]{%
\setbox\xratbelow=\hbox{\ensuremath{\scriptstyle #1}}%
\setbox\xratabove=\hbox{\ensuremath{\scriptstyle #2}}%
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\xratlen}{max(\wd\xratbelow, \wd\xratabove) + .6em}%
\mathrel{\tikz [->, baseline=-.75ex]
\draw (0,0) -- node[below=-2pt] {\box\xratbelow}
node[above] {\box\xratabove}
(\xratlen,0) ;}}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext
\[
    A \xrightarrow{\sim} B
\]
\blindtext
\[
    A \overset{\sim}{\to} B
\]
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

The vertical spaces you were talking about are not modified by the `\baseline` command which is needed to have the arrow at the correct position, but by the inner space of the two nodes.

I slightly modified the `\renewcommand{xrightarrow}`. On the above page, it is used in the second centered equation.  As you can see, now there is no difference with respect to the first one where  `\longrightarrow` is used.

**Remark.** When *1/x* replaces *~*, the vertical spaces will remain the same.

**The code**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{parskip}

\RequirePackage{tikz-cd}
\newbox\xratbelow
\newbox\xratabove
\renewcommand{\xrightarrow}[2][]{%
  \setbox\xratbelow=\hbox{\ensuremath{\scriptstyle #1}}%
  \setbox\xratabove=\hbox{\ensuremath{\scriptstyle #2}}%
  \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\xratlen}{max(\wd\xratbelow, \wd\xratabove) + .8em}%
  \hspace{.2ex}\mathrel{\tikz[->, baseline=-.75ex,
    every node/.style={inner sep=.5pt}]
    \draw (0,0) -- node[below=2pt] {\box\xratbelow}
    node[above=2pt] {\box\xratabove} (\xratlen, 0);
  }\hspace{.2ex}
}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \draw[red] (0, -3.82) rectangle ++(12.1, -1.3)
  ++(0, .51) -- ++(-12.1, 0);
  \draw[red] (0, -9.16) rectangle ++(12.1, -1.3)
  ++(0, .51) -- ++(-12.1, 0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\blindtext
\[
  A \overset{\sim}{\longrightarrow} B
\]
\blindtext
\[
  A \xrightarrow{\sim} B
\]
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! May I ask two questions: 1) Why did you set `style={inner sep=.5pt}` instead of `style={inner sep=0pt}`? 2)What does the "1/x replaces ~" in your remark stand for?

Comment: 1) If you change `.5pt` to `0pt`, you will see that the label above the arrow is placed too close to the arrow.  Anyway, the result will look different from what `\overset{\sim}{\to}` gives.

Comment: 2) I was talking about an example with a more complicated label, say `\frac{1}{x}` which forces the vertical space between the text and the equation to be bigger; the comparison is acceptable, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Just for reference, based on Daniel's answer, here is the complete definition for all those retractable arrows. The behavior is not quite the same as `\overset`, but in consistent with Asana Math / Tex Gyre Pagella Math or similar math fonts.

```
% The following uses tikz-cd to define retractable arrows to avoid problems with unicode-math.
\newbox\xratbelow
\newbox\xratabove
% Redefine \xrightarrow[below]{above}
\renewcommand{\xrightarrow}[2][]{%
    \setbox\xratbelow=\hbox{\ensuremath{\scriptstyle #1}}%
    \setbox\xratabove=\hbox{\ensuremath{\scriptstyle #2}}%
    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\xratlen}{max(\wd\xratbelow, \wd\xratabove) + .8em}%
    \mathrel{\tikz [->, baseline=-.6ex, every node/.style={inner sep=0pt}]
        \draw (0,0) -- node[below=3pt] {\box\xratbelow}
        node[above=2pt] {\box\xratabove}
        (\xratlen,0) ;}}
% Redefine \xlefttarrow[below]{above}
\renewcommand{\xleftarrow}[2][]{%
    \setbox\xratbelow=\hbox{\ensuremath{\scriptstyle #1}}%
    \setbox\xratabove=\hbox{\ensuremath{\scriptstyle #2}}%
    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\xratlen}{max(\wd\xratbelow, \wd\xratabove) + .8em}%
    \mathrel{\tikz [<-, baseline=-.6ex, every node/.style={inner sep=0pt}]
        \draw (0,0) -- node[below=3pt] {\box\xratbelow}
        node[above=2pt] {\box\xratabove}
        (\xratlen,0) ;}}
% Redefine \xleftrightarrow[below]{above}
\renewcommand{\xleftrightarrow}[2][]{%
    \setbox\xratbelow=\hbox{\ensuremath{\scriptstyle #1}}%
    \setbox\xratabove=\hbox{\ensuremath{\scriptstyle #2}}%
    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\xratlen}{max(\wd\xratbelow, \wd\xratabove) + .8em}%
    \mathrel{\tikz [<->, baseline=-.6ex, every node/.style={inner sep=0pt}]
        \draw (0,0) -- node[below=3pt] {\box\xratbelow}
        node[above=2pt] {\box\xratabove}
        (\xratlen,0) ;}}
% Redefine \xhookrightarrow[below]{above}, using the hookrightarrow from tikz-cd
\renewcommand{\xhookrightarrow}[2][]{%
    \setbox\xratbelow=\hbox{\ensuremath{\scriptstyle #1}}%
    \setbox\xratabove=\hbox{\ensuremath{\scriptstyle #2}}%
    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\xratlen}{max(\wd\xratbelow, \wd\xratabove) + .8em}%
    \mathrel{\tikz [baseline=-.6ex, every node/.style={inner sep=0pt}]
        \draw (0,0) edge[commutative diagrams/hookrightarrow] node[below=3pt] {\box\xratbelow}
        node[above=2pt] {\box\xratabove}
        (\xratlen,0) ;}}
% Redefine \xhooklefttarrow[below]{above}, using the hookleftarrow from tikz-cd
\renewcommand{\xhookleftarrow}[2][]{%
    \setbox\xratbelow=\hbox{\ensuremath{\scriptstyle #1}}%
    \setbox\xratabove=\hbox{\ensuremath{\scriptstyle #2}}%
    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\xratlen}{max(\wd\xratbelow, \wd\xratabove) + .8em}%
    \mathrel{\tikz [baseline=-.6ex, every node/.style={inner sep=0pt}]
        \draw (0,0) edge[commutative diagrams/hookleftarrow] node[below=3pt] {\box\xratbelow}
        node[above=2pt] {\box\xratabove}
        (\xratlen,0) ;}}
% Redefine \xmapsto[below]{above}, using the mapsto from tikz-cd
\renewcommand{\xmapsto}[2][]{%
    \setbox\xratbelow=\hbox{\ensuremath{\scriptstyle #1}}%
    \setbox\xratabove=\hbox{\ensuremath{\scriptstyle #2}}%
    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\xratlen}{max(\wd\xratbelow, \wd\xratabove) + .8em}%
    \mathrel{\tikz [baseline=-.6ex, every node/.style={inner sep=0pt}]
        \draw (0,0) edge[commutative diagrams/mapsto] node[below=3pt] {\box\xratbelow}
        node[above=2pt] {\box\xratabove}
        (\xratlen,0) ;}}
% Define \xlongequal[below]{above}, using the equal from tikz-cd
\newcommand{\xlongequal}[2][]{%
    \setbox\xratbelow=\hbox{\ensuremath{\scriptstyle #1}}%
    \setbox\xratabove=\hbox{\ensuremath{\scriptstyle #2}}%
    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\xratlen}{max(\wd\xratbelow, \wd\xratabove) + .8em}%
    \mathrel{\tikz [baseline=-.6ex, every node/.style={inner sep=0pt}]
        \draw (0,0) edge[commutative diagrams/equal] node[below=3pt] {\box\xratbelow}
        node[above=2pt] {\box\xratabove}
        (\xratlen,0) ;}}
```